# Different ItemsSource to each user control

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In my window I have ListBox that contain collection of usercontrols like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserControls}">
```

Inside the user control class I have DataGrid that bind to datatable:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableResult}"/>
```

From the window's viewmodel I'm adding dynamiclly more usercontrols to the ListBox, like:

```
void AddUserControl()
{
   MyUserControl uc = new MyUserControl
   {
     DataContext = this
   };
   UserControls.Add(uc);
}
```

For now all the usercontrols bind to the same table: **TableResult**

But what I what is a new DataTable for each usercontrol.

I have tried like:

```
void AddUserControl()
{
   MyUserControl uc = new MyUserControl
   {
     DataContext = this
   };
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   uc.MyGridView.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
   UserControls.Add(uc);
}
```

but now this part will be missing for the new datatable:

```
DataTable dt;
public DataTable Dt
{
    get { return dt; }
    set
    {
        dt = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Dt");
     }
}
```

Note: I have only one viewmodel for the window, therefore the datacontext of each usercontrol is the same viewmodel

Any suggestions for this secnario? I mean how do I bind a new datatable for each new usercontrol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't bind to an `IEnumerable<UserControl>`. Referencing UI elements or controls in a view model breaks the MVVM pattern.

What you should do is to create a class to which you add the `DataTable` property and then bind to an `IEnumerable<YourClass>`. The actual `UserControl` should be defined in the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox` in the view:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataObjects}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <local:MyUserControl  />
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The root element in the `ItemTemplate` inherits its `DataContext` from the current item in the `ListBox` which means that you can bind directly to any public property of `YourClass` in `MyUserControl`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TableProperty}"/>
```

Comment: Where `TableProperty` will be? at the new class? in the viewmodel?

Comment: @Codey: In the new class that I've called `YourClass` in my example.

Comment: I will continue tommorrow for mor questions, thanks

Comment: @Codey: Please ask a new question if you have another issue or any further questions around your original issue.